# Display Image in place of Flash .swf file when Flash is not installed or enabled

Tags: javascript, image, flash

My website will have a logo on the header that will play as a flash movie (animated flash movie .swf). I am looking for code / algorithm that will display an image with the same dimensions as the flash movie if Flash is not installed or enabled for the current user accessing the site. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use general object fallback detection. The way this works is that anything the browser doesn't know how to render in the object tag, it will fall through to the content inside.

A clipped version of your code would look similar to this:

```
<object id="my-flash" src="movie.swf" width="800" height="600">
    <img src="fallback_image.jpg" width="800" height="600" />
</object>
```

Of course, you would need to wrap your actual Flash embed HTML around the image, but that's the idea.

Comment: Gotcha. Would this have cross-browser compatibility? And what about different versions of Flash?

Comment: Every browser that I know of supports the idea of object fallback, which is why you see `<object><embed /></object>` in a lot of Flash embed code. IIRC, object is the correct way of embedding Flash, and embed is the fallback in case object doesn't work. In your case, you would likely have several nested layers of fallback: `<object><embed><img/></embed></object>`

Comment: As for different Flash versions, another option is to use something like SWFObject and only replace your main <img/> if Flash is detected. The image is there by default, and SWFObject will go and replace it if it can find a compatible version of Flash.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) for this. It works great, it will work cross-browser, and you can specify which version of Flash you are looking for (this could be key since there are some major differences). Check [this tutorial on providing alternative content](http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/flashplayer/articles/alternative_content.html), which is exactly what you want to do.